# QZ-Tray showing website as untrusted on the pop-up when trying to connect and print

Tags: php, cloudflare, self-signed, qz-tray

I am trying to use QZ-Tray to print labels at a terminal in my workshop. I have all of the program working however I want to remove the annoying '... wants to connect to QZ Tray **Untrusted Website**' pop-up. I have installed the certificate and the private key in the signing script. However I still get the pop-up, the information from the certificate is showing i.e. Organization, Common Name etc but it is showing under the Certificate section that Trusted = **Untrusted Website** and then under the Request section Validity = **Invalid Certificate**.

Below is the details box that appears when trying to complete an action.

Request

| Call | connect |
| --- | --- |
| Parameters | {} |
| Signature | Not Required |
| Timestamp | 1686732120276 |
| Validity | Invalid Certificate |

Certificate

| Organization | CloudFlare, Inc. |
| --- | --- |
| Common Name | CloudFlare Origin Certificate |
| Trusted | Untrusted Website |
| Valid From | 2023-06-14 08:22:00 |
| Valid To | 2038-06-10-08:22:00 |
| Fingerprint | Omitted |

Comment: Hi, you've tagged `cloudfare`, `php`, `self-signed` and `qz-tray`, however the question only contains high-level questions about `qz-tray`.  Please consider improving the question by providing technical details you've performed as well as steps (including code) to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

This indicates you never [overrode the default certificate](https://qz.io/docs/signing#to-override-the-trusted-root-certificate).

In order to use QZ Tray in a self-signed fashion, you will need to:

1. [Override the built-in trusted root certificate](https://qz.io/docs/signing#to-override-the-trusted-root-certificate)
   **Note:** QZ can do this for you using the [DEMO Keys](https://qz.io/docs/signing#demo-keys) feature.
2. Setup [`setCertificatePromise()`](https://qz.io/docs/signing#setcertificatepromise) using JavaScript
3. Setup [`setSignaturePromise()`](https://qz.io/docs/signing#setsignaturepromise) using JavaScript and a back-end language

   **⚠️ Warning:**  If you decide to use [pure front-end JavaScript for signing](https://qz.io/docs/signing-examples#edit-the-signing-function), it can leak your private key to the browser.